# Insert a WPF Resource Dictionary into a class library via Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a class library and want to change the type so that I also can add a WPF resource dictionaries. I have added the WPF references and also tried to sync the AssemblyInfo.cs file with a project that allows the addition of such resource files, however without success.

If I use the add-new-dialog from Visual Studio, the template for WPF resource dictionaries is not available - If I create the file manually and then reference it, all works fine.

How can I change my project to a WPF custom control library project so that Visual Studio allows me to add WPF resource dictionaries. Or are there any drawbacks or pitfalls so that I must not do that and better create a new project-file?

Comment: Why would you want to put the resource dictionary into a class library in the first place? My understanding is that the class library project is generally not meant to store any UI pertinent information.

Comment: Yeah I would use the custom control library or user control library depending on your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be defined in the csproj-File. If I add the following line into the PropertyGroup-Section, I can do what I'm looking for:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

**Please note**
Although I have found the location where the definiton resides, I have not used the changed version of the csproj-File. I have created a new project with the desired settings. There seem to be a lot of additional project-settings between a control library and a class library and maybe only adding the above guids may result in unexpected behaviour of the project/solution.

Comment: I guess you can mark the question as answered but it still feels a little dirty to be storing layout specific code (even if it's only datatemplates) in a class library project. That's just my opinion though.

Comment: @DeviantSeev: The project is no more a class library. It's used as a custom control library and for the controls I need the templates. There's nothing wrong with this. The dirty thing is the way I changed the project type - I don't know if there are other settings at different locations and if this lead to problems in the future. Thats why I have created in the meantime a new project. But I think the question is worth an answer anyhow: Maybe it helps somebody with a similar problem.