# C# Class Library project type in Visual Studio missing WPF Resource Dictionary item in menu

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

My code customizes a WPF `ListBox` object using styles.  I would like to convert this code into a class definition (for reuse).  Since I am not extending the `ListBox` but only styling it, I am told in various textbooks and by experts that a *User Control* or a *Custom Control* is not necessary.

So, I choose the "C# Class Library" project type from Visual Studio to create the class code.  However, because this type of project is generic and not WPF-specific, when I try to add a Resource Dictionary to my class, that option is missing from the Add menu (see picture).

[image]

This makes me question whether I am on the right track to begin with?

I have checked other related SO questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605987/insert-a-wpf-resource-dictionary-into-a-class-library-via-visual-studio-2010)) but none of them show how to create a WPF-specific class library that is not a user or custom control).

C#, Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Yeah, you're fine.  Just use Add>New Item... and search for the proper Resource template.  Done.

Comment: @Will Unbelievable! Thank you. Once I went into the online template search, it was the second item under the WPF templates. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can also drag a RsrcDict from a WPF app to a Class lib.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Drag, as in... copy the file in and add it as an existing item?

Comment: That might work too but but you can just drag&drop in the Solution window. You may have to add a few references afterwards.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I see, thank you.  I guess I need to change my erroneous perspective that if it's not built into VS, then it must not be allowed.

Comment: Yes, you certainly should. VS offers a large set of templates and commands but much more is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you're fine. Just use Add>New Item... and search for the proper Resource template. Done.

Options in that menu are based on the project type.  They're barely useful.  I usually always use the dialog and search to find my templates.

Comment: Will, have to say I like your easy going style! I was under pressure here, and your "Yeah, you're fine..." response took the pressure off!  Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, you're fine on this point, but in general you're in super trouble.  Stress on!

Comment: ;-) Can you also please comment on what I mentioned about user and custom controls?

Comment: Yeah, you're fine on that too.  I've done it before, creating custom controls and control templates in a DLL project.  Sometimes it's a bit complex; IIRC, there are issues with URIs that have to be different inside the dll and outisde it, but once you get that straight it works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot